# How can I make this Peano addition algorithm work without using a loop?

Tags: javascript, recursion, peano-numbers

Can someone please explain how to do make this work without a loop?

```js
let x = prompt("Enter a first number to add:");
let y = prompt("Enter a second number to add:");
parseFloat(x);
parseFloat(y);

alert(peanoAddition(x, y));

function peanoAddition(x, y) {
  while (y !== 0) {
    if (y === 0) {
      return x;
    } else {
      x = x + 1;
      y = y - 1;
      return x;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Your `return` statements don't really make sense, you always return from the first iteration of the loop, and if `y` is passed `0` then your function returns `undefined`. You probably meant `while (y != 0) { x += 1; y -= 1; } return x;`

Comment: @Bergi: Thanks for your feedback. This is an exercise for a class I'm taking. The rules of the exercise state that this function is supposed to be recursive. Therefore using a loop is not allowed.

Answer (score 1):

This is fairly simple to change to a recursive function. Your terminating condition will be the same: `if (y === 0) return x`. Otherwise, you just call `peanoAddition` again with the new arguments for `x` and `y` and return the result.

Then, if `y` is not 0, the function gets called again and again until `y` is 0.

The following works exactly the same as your code. *However*, it keeps the same issues as well. For example, what happens when you call `peanoAddition(5, -2)`? Both your code and mine will run forever.

```js
function peanoAddition(x, y) {
  if (y === 0) {
    return x;
  }
  return peanoAddition(x + 1, y - 1);
}
```

Comment: There's one thing I'd like to add that would be helpful: 

`function peanoAddition(x, y) 
{
   if (x === 0)
   {
          return y
   }
     else if (y === 0) 
     {
         return x;
     }
else  {
x++
y--
}
  return peanoAddition(x, y);
}`

Data validation wasn't a requirement. That's a good point. IF (x<0 || y <0 ) { //prompt for input?}